# Responsive Vertical Tabs to accordion on the right side

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make vertical tabs on the right side using a responsive design. I tried searching on how to make it and so far I got something that I want which is like http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kJGBL?editors=010

HTML

```
<ul class="tabs">
  <li class="active" rel="tab1">Tab 1</li>
  <li rel="tab2">Tab 2</li>
  <li rel="tab3">Tab 3</li>
  <li rel="tab4">Tab 4</li>

</ul>
<div class="tab_container">
  <h3 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab 1</h3>
  <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 1 content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec ac metus augue.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab1 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab 2</h3>
  <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 2 content</h2>
    <p>Nunc dui velit, scelerisque eu placerat volutpat, dapibus eu nisi. Vivamus eleifend vestibulum odio non vulputate.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab2 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab 3</h3>
  <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 3 content</h2>
    <p>Nulla eleifend felis vitae velit tristique imperdiet. Etiam nec imperdiet elit. Pellentesque sem lorem, scelerisque sed facilisis sed, vestibulum sit amet eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab3 -->
  <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab4">Tab 4</h3>
  <div id="tab4" class="tab_content">
  <h2>Tab 4 content</h2>
    <p>Integer ultrices lacus sit amet lorem viverra consequat. Vivamus lacinia interdum sapien non faucibus. Maecenas bibendum, lectus at ultrices viverra, elit magna egestas magna, a adipiscing mauris justo nec eros.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- #tab4 --> 
</div>
<!-- .tab_container -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
ul.tabs {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    height: 32px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    width: 100%;
}

ul.tabs li {
    float: right;
  display: block;
    margin: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px 21px;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 31px;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    border-left: 1px solid #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    background-color: #666;
    color: #ccc;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.tab_last { border-right: 1px solid #333; }

ul.tabs li:hover {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #333;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    display: block;
}

.tab_container {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    border-top: none;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
}

.tab_content {
    padding: 20px;
    display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .tabs {
        display: none;
    }
    .tab_drawer_heading {
        background-color: #ccc;
        color: #fff;
        border-top: 1px solid #333;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
    }
    .d_active {
        background-color: #666;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

but the problem is that the tabs are horizontal. I want my tabs to be vertical and on the right side of the container.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following CSS with your HTML:

```
ul.tabs {  
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  height: 32px; 
  width: 20%;
}

ul.tabs li {
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 21px;
  height: 31px;
  line-height: 31px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  background-color: #666;
  color: #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.tab_last { border-right: 1px solid #333; }

ul.tabs li:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
}

ul.tabs li.active {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  display: block;
}

.tab_container {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  float: left;
  width: 79%;
  background: #fff;
}

.tab_content {
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
}

.tab_drawer_heading { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

  .tab_container {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .tabs {
    display: none;
  }
  .tab_drawer_heading {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 1px solid #333;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
  }
  .d_active {
    background-color: #666;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
```